# MySQL trigger query is not working?

Tags: android

The query for inserting values in to temp_refillsales and the consumerno, orderno and orderdate and time is taken from the android app. Please help me how to give values from android app to mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER `bookin_insert` AFTER INSERT ON  `refillsales` 
FOR EACH
ROW INSERT INTO temp_refillsales( ConsumerNo, OrderNo, OrderDateAndTime ) 
VALUES ('$ConsumerNo',  '$OrderNo',  '$OrderDateAndTime')
```